# Prove for all subsets $M$ of $A$ the following $M \subseteq f^{-1}(f(M))$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm doing a past exam as preparation for the upcoming exam. It contains the following problem

**Let $f: A \longrightarrow B$ be a mapping.**

**(a) Prove for all subsets $M$ of $A$ the following 
$M \subseteq f^{-1}(f(M))$.**

I have spent a good hour thinking about this... nothing substantial has come to my mind, sorry.
***Which theorems, definitions, corollaries etc. should I use?***
I will probably try to study these harder because I probably do not have a sufficient understanding.

**(b) Give an example which shows that $f^{-1}(f(M))$ do not have to be equal to $M$.**

This one I can probably solve if I get sufficient help with (a).

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

X

Comment: How about the definition of $f^{-1}(X)$: $a\in f^{-1}(X)$ iff $f(a)\in X$? So $a\in f^{-1}(f(M))$ iff $f(a)\in f(M)$.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! This is the definition of a inverse mapping, right? But $f$ does not have to be invertible ?

Comment: also, put $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^2$. then for M={2}. we have $f(M)={4}$, and $f^{-1}(f(M))=f^{-1}(\{4\})=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2=4\}=\{2,-2\}$

Comment: Thanks. Seems like an easy and understandable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for a function $f:A\to B$, for any $M\subseteq A$ and $N\subseteq B$ we have  $$f(M)=\{f(x)\mid x\in M\}\\f^{-1}(N)=\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in N\}$$

Let $M\subseteq A$ be given.  Let $x\in M$ be given.  Then $f(x)\in f(M)$ from the first definition.  Therefore, $x\in f^{-1}(f(M))$, again from the second definition because $f(x)\in f(M)$.  Since $x$ was arbitrary, $M\subseteq f^{-1}(f(M))$

Remember that $f^{-1}(f(M))$ is the set of all members of the domain whose output under $f$ is the output under $f$ from some member of $M$.  So, of course any member of $M$ would satisfy that.  This is one of those problems that is so easy that you can get bogged down by all the notation.

For your second question, imagine that $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is the constant function $f(x)=0$.  Let $M=\{1\}$.  Then $f(M)=\{0\}$ because $f(1)=0$.  But $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\mathbb R$, because every element maps to $0$.  Therefore, this is a case where $f^{-1}(f(M))\neq M$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand fully! 
Why do you use $\subset$ instead of $\subseteq$ ?

Comment: @Xenusi because half of mathematicians think that extra line is a waste of pencil lead and we use $\subsetneq$ in the rare cases when we want to talk about proper subsets.  ^_^  I should have noticed it and adapted -- it is now edited.

Comment: 
Once again, thanks.